# How the fetch the value of textBox Using Javascript in Selenium webDriver?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]I wanted to get the text inside the input tag which is not available in my HTML. So I have to use JS for getting the value. But I am getting null as the result when running in eclipse. I have added the HTML and Selenium code in the below screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = 'estimatedDepositRate']")).getAttribute("value")`? You need to use javascript? off: That is an input, not textBox

Comment: there is no value property in the html Dom. Hence I didn't tried

Comment: If you don't see it in `Inspect`, that doesn't mean there is no `value` property.

Comment: It is working...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**In Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("estimatedDepositRate").value;
```

> This can be achieve in selenium using **JavascriptExecutor** :

```
String estimatedDepositRate  = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById("estimatedDepositRate").value");
```

**Normal Code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("estimatedDepositRate")).getAttribute("value")
```

***Note:*** Kindly cast the estimatedDepositRate value to **String** if you get any error.